# Internet explorer and tabbing out of datalist

Tags: internet-explorer, browser

Chrome and firefox work fine, but when in internet explorer a tab out of a datalist does not select the option, bit it does in other browsers.

Load the below fiddle in IE and any other browser.  Click in the field and hit the arrow down key a few times.  Then hit tab and you will see what I am talking about.

https://jsfiddle.net/v6uvagd2/

```
    <div>

    <label for="client">Member</label>
<input type="text" name="client" autofocus="autofocus" id="client" list="allclients" required="required" placeholder="Start typing..." value="" />
<datalist id="allclients">
<select>
<option value="yada">yada</option>
<option value="bada">bada</option>
<option value="nada">nada</option>
</select>
</datalist>

</div>
```

Is there a way to get IE to work like the other browsers?